# webshim mediaelement / kaltura CE / mediaelement.js as platform for developing advanced player

Tags: html5-video, media-player, mediaelement.js, kaltura, webshim

I am trying to develop a custom self-hosted embedable player (Just YT embeds for now, but option for adding media later) with social media buttons, clickable overlays, post-roll options, etc that can be shared in FB timeline cross-browser, etc. I have narrowed down frameworks to:

1. [Mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)
2. [Kaltura Community Edition](http://www.kaltura.org/project/community_edition_video_platform)
3. [Webshim's mediaelement](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/)

I'm new to javascript, so ease of use, user base, and documentation are all important. Any reason why one of these might be a dead-end for my purposes, or why one might be easier to develop for?

Just trying to get perspective at the moment before drilling down on the development details. I am experimenting with mediaelement.js in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it won't be easy.
You also must have a server side for in order to create your own player.
I know that Kaltura are working on a solution.
But I don't see any better choices.